# Is it possible to scan with an Android/ios device for other Android/ios devices' UUIDs or mac addresses in the background via Bluetooth LE?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm not a developer but I'm curious about the connectivity options between smartphones.
Looks like BLE is the only technology that is available on both Android and ios that could make an connection possible in the foreground, but is able to scan in the background?

If I walked around with my phone in the pocket, could it scan in intervalls for other devices`UUIDs/mac addresses and save the data realibly without the process being shut down after a while?

the app would have to work between Android phones, ios Devices, 
and Android phones-ios Devices.

I dont want a stable connection. I'm only speaking about gathering UUIDs and mac adresses in the background. whichever is more suitable to uniquely identify a device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS devices with BLE support can act as the peripheral and/or the central role. The peripheral advertises its services, and the central discovers them (via scanning). You need Android 5.0+ to support peripheral mode.

Once a central discovers a peripheral, the central can obtain advertisement details from it, including a unique peripheral ID. This is similar to a MAC address, though some peripherals randomly generate these IDs.

In general, an iOS or Android device acts in the central role and it doesn't advertise anything. There is nothing to discover. However, you could write an app that acts as both a peripheral and a central.

On iOS, your app [can perform both BLE roles in the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) (your app doesn't need to be in the foreground).

You would want to do background tasks responsibly as both advertising and scanning require the radio, which uses a significant amount of power (drains the battery).

There are many issues with the current BLE stack on Android (e.g. using WIFI and BLE at the same time because they share the radio). The BLE API first became available for Android with 4.2.

The iPhone 4s and later has BLE with the API first available in iOS 6.